# Comparing data on Landing zone with staging zone in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, querying, delta

Here is the following requirement, there are two tables **`T1_D1`** and **`T2_D2`.** Where **`T1_D1`** has **4 records**, and **`T2_D2`** has **6 records** which has  **Inserts, Updates**.

Now, I need to compare both the tables and should update all the modifications on the table **`T1_D1`**.

**Sample data: `T1_D1`**

| ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | PRODUCT | PRICE | IS_UPDATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2009 13:08 | Product1 | 350 | N |
| 2 | 01/02/2009 12:56 | Product2 | 1300 | N |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1250 | N |
| 4 | 01/02/2009 18:48 | Product1 | 1450 | N |

**Sample data: `T1_D2`**

| ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | PRODUCT | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2009 13:08 | Product1 | 350 |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1250 |
| 4 | 01/02/2009 18:48 | Product1 | 1450 |
| 5 | 01/02/2009 20:09 | Product1 | 1200 |
| 6 | 01/02/2009 15:56 | Product5 | 1300 |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1350 |

**Final Result:**

| ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | PRODUCT | PRICE | IS_UPDATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2009 13:08 | Product1 | 350 | N |
| 2 | 01/02/2009 12:56 | Product2 | 1300 | N |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1250 | Y |
| 4 | 01/02/2009 18:48 | Product1 | 1450 | N |
| 5 | 01/02/2009 20:09 | Product1 | 1200 | N |
| 6 | 01/02/2009 15:56 | Product5 | 1300 | N |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1350 | N |

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed solution:**

1. First find **T2_D2 - T1_D1 => Which gives us the delta i.e Inserted and updated, and append those to the t1_d1.** in this context, appended in the sense inserted.

**Actual result set of above query :**

| ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | PRODUCT | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 01/02/2009 20:09 | Product1 | 1200 |
| 6 | 01/02/2009 15:56 | Product5 | 1300 |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1350 |

2. After insert the table looks like the following.

| ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | PRODUCT | PRICE | IS_UPDATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2009 13:08 | Product1 | 350 | N |
| 2 | 01/02/2009 12:56 | Product2 | 1300 | N |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1250 | N |
| 4 | 01/02/2009 18:48 | Product1 | 1450 | N |
| 5 | 01/02/2009 20:09 | Product1 | 1200 | N |
| 6 | 01/02/2009 15:56 | Product5 | 1300 | N |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1350 | N |

3. According to this table the unique values are never changed **i.e ID, PRODUCT is never changed rather every  other value is changed,** so i have maintained a table called **config_pull** which has the following schema.

| ID | TABLE_NAME | COLS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1_D1 | ID,PRODUCT |

4. Now I have written a procedure, that fetches the result set of the **config_pull** and dynamically it generates a query for the above requirement.
   i.e the query looks like

`SELECT  T.ID, T.TRANSACTION_DATE, T.PRODUCT  FROM  T1_D1 as T,(SELECT ID,TRANSACTION_DATE,PRODUCT from T1_D2 EXCEPT SELECT ID,TRANSACTION_DATE,PRODUCT FROM T1_D1) as M WHERE M.ID = T.ID`

5. The above query gives the actual updated rows on the DAY-1.

| ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | PRODUCT | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1250 |

6. Later Write an update Statement to update all the rows fetched from the above query, in T1_D1 i.e .

| ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | PRODUCT | PRICE | IS_UPDATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1250 | Y |

**Final Result**

| ID | TRANSACTION_DATE | PRODUCT | PRICE | IS_UPDATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2009 13:08 | Product1 | 350 | N |
| 2 | 01/02/2009 12:56 | Product2 | 1300 | N |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1250 | Y |
| 4 | 01/02/2009 18:48 | Product1 | 1450 | N |
| 5 | 01/02/2009 20:09 | Product1 | 1200 | N |
| 6 | 01/02/2009 15:56 | Product5 | 1300 | N |
| 3 | 01/02/2009 14:58 | Product2 | 1350 | N |

7. Now if you want to run this on 100 tables or 200 tables, first store all the key required columns in a table an write a procedure for it, in order to dynamically perform the updates and everything without manual intervention.

**Please Let me Know if you find any other approach to solve this problem in a different way, without using the unique columns approach.**

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Snowflake, another approach is to use their "table streams" methodology for 'change data capture'.

See [Snowflake CDC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html#change-tracking-using-table-streams)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `MERGE` statement:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

It can update, insert, and delete in one step:

```sql
merge into target_table using source_table 
    on target_table.id = source_table.id
    when matched then 
        update set target_table.description = source_table.description
    when not matched then 
        insert (id, description) values (source_table.id, source_table.description);
```

Looking at your question it seems that:

- `target_table` is `T1_D1`
- `source_table` is `T2_D2`
- `on target_table.id = source_table.id` is `T1_D1.transaction_date=T2_D2.transaction_date and T1_D1.product=T2_D2.product`
- The update would change the price, changing `target_table.description = source_table.description` to `T1_D1.price = T2_D2.price`
- The insert should be changed to match an insert into T1_D1.

Comment: If i use the merge approach then it directly updates the value of the row in T1_D1, instead i need a new row for the updated one. like the one i demonstrated in the example.